# useSelector constant not updating after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-moon-9ehen).

`getIDs()` updates `cells`, which is then needed by `initializeCells()`. However, this change is not reflected after dispatching the action. Despite that, I can see on [Redux dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) that the action got through and the value of `cells` has changed accordingly. `gameStart()` is being passed via props to `cells`, a child component, and called there via the `useEffect()` hook. I need to pass an empty array as the second argument for this hook or it will run forever, as the state updates every time it's called. The problem is that the new state is not available for the following functions after `getIDs()` on its first run. It seems to be when `gameStart()` has fully finished and has been called again. I need to have the piece of state that `initializeCells()` needs updated right after `getIDs()` is done.

**cells.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import Cell from "./Container/Container/Cell";

const Cells = props => {
  const board = useSelector(state => state.board);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.gameStart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="cells">
      {board.map(cell => {
        return (
          <Cell
            id={cell.id.substring(1)}
            key={cell.id.substring(1)}
            className="cell"
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cells;
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import {
  setCells,
  setBoard
} from "../../redux/actions/index";

const Game = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cells = useSelector(state => state.cells);
  const board = useSelector(state => state.board);
  const boardSize = useSelector(state => state.boardSize);

  async function gameStart() {
    await getIDs();
    console.log(cells); // []
    await initializeCells();
    await assignSnake();
    await placeFood();
    await paintCells();
  }

  function getIDs() {
    let cellID = "";
    let collection = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= boardSize.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j <= boardSize.columns; j++) {
        cellID = `#cell-${i}-${j}`;

        collection.push(cellID);
      }
    }
    dispatch(setCells(collection));
    console.log(cells); // []
  }

  function initializeCells() {
    console.log(cells); // []
    const board = [];
    // for loop never runs because cells is empty
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      board.push(cell(cells[i]));
    }
    dispatch(setBoard(board));
    console.log("Board: ", board); // []
  }

  function cell(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      row: id.match("-(.*)-")[1],
      column: id.substr(id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1),
      hasFood: false,
      hasSnake: false
    };
  }

  return (
  ...
  )
}

export default Game;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import {
  SET_CELLS,
  SET_BOARD
} from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  board: [],
  cells: [],
  boardSize: {
    rows: 25,
    columns: 40
  }
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CELLS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        cells: action.payload
      });

    case SET_BOARD:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        board: action.payload
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import {
  SET_CELLS,
  SET_BOARD
} from "../constants/action-types";

export const setCells = payload => {
  return { type: SET_CELLS, payload };
};

export const setBoard = payload => {
  return { type: SET_BOARD, payload };
};
```

**constants/action-types.js**

```
export const SET_CELLS = "SET_CELLS";
export const SET_BOARD = "SET_BOARD";
```

Comment: It seems like you need to make use of `useEffect` in the component logic, using the dependencies array.

Comment: Can you expand on that? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Sure. Right now you are defining functions inside the component, but these functions need to be called again when the parameters inside them change. To achieve this I think the approach should be using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: I have changed the component where the function was called. It was first called through ```componentDidMount()``` and now it uses ```useEffect()```. After this, the function was being infinitely called, so I had to pass an empty array as the second argument to ```useEffect()```. This has not changed anything, however, and I am still encountering the same problem.

Comment: Could you expand the component, where is `gameStart` being called? What is it rendering?

Comment: I have updated the post with more information.

Comment: Thanks for expanding, but still could you expand on the Game component. `gameStart` is calling functions that dont appear in the answer (like `assignSnake`) so its difficult to say what they are doing and what do they depend on. Also why does `gameStart` need to be passed to `Cells`, why can it be called in the same way but inside `Game`?

Comment: The other functions besides ```getIDs()``` and ```initializeCells()``` are irrelevant as long as these two work properly; they might as well not be there. ```gameStart()``` is run at the rendering of a child component for performance reasons. My problem is that ```initializeCells()``` is dependant on ```cells```, an array variable that is set by ```getIDs()```. The latter function doesn't apply the ```dispatch()``` method until ```gameStart()``` is done. This means that when ```initializeCells()``` accesses ```cells``` it gets an empty array, as shown by the ```console.log()``` statements.

Comment: `dispatch(setBoard(board));
    console.log("Board: ", board); // []` does that code mean you expect `board` variable to be updated in the same `render()` run where `dispatch` happens?

Comment: Yes, is that not possible? The functions inside ```gameStart()``` take variables that are inside the redux store. I have just switched to redux, before I was using a class component with local state and it worked properly, granted I had to make ```gameStart()``` an asynchronous function and await for every function inside of it to apply ```this.setState()```, which now is replaced by ```dispatch()```

Answer (score 3):

After dispatching some action updated store will be provided only on next render. This is the same for functional with hooks and classes with `connect` HOC.

You need to change your code not to expect changes immediately. It's hard for me understand your intention here, you may start with just rendering what it comes and dispatch-and-forget approach with actions. And it should work.

If it does not, make minimal sample(only relevant hooks + how data is rendered) and also describe what you want to get(instead of "how")

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you rethink all the patterns here and think about what is informing your decisions before writing code. First, why set the state like this at all? If using state is justified, why create separate `cells` and `board` state values when you're only accessing `board` in your `Cells` component? Are any of the values such as `boardSize` going to be controlled? Perhaps they will be called from a remote network resource when the app loads and you don't know them right away? If no to either of those, there's not really any good reason to store them in state, and they can just be constants declared at initialization outside of your components. If yes, the code should fit the use-case. If you are going to have user controlled board size, you should initialize your values with defaults and handle all synchronous state changes with no side effects within your reducer.

Also, just so you know, the way you're using async functions is kind of an anti-pattern. With Redux, if you're using true async functions, i.e. calling a network resources, you could use [thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), and call `getState()` within a thunk each time you need to access the updated state after a `dispatch`.

Otherwise, are you familiar with the class component lifecycle pattern of `componentDidUpdate`? Essentially you "listen" for state changes and only call a function that relies on changed state after it changes. One way you can do that with hooks is `useEffect` with a dependency array containing the state you're relying on, meaning it'll only be called when those dependencies are changed, and you can do further conditional checks within the `useEffect` function (but *never* wrap `useEffect` in a conditional!). Things get more complicated here when using objects or arrays as dependencies, however, as it uses a strict equality check so you may need to use a ref and compare current and previous values within `useEffect`, with something like [this usePrevious hook](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/).

All that said, in your current use-case you don't need to do any of this because you're simply synchronously initializing static values. I would personally not even store this in state if the `boardSize` values are not controlled, but for the sake of education here's how you'd do it in the reducer.

First, simply `disptach({ type: 'INITIALIZE_BOARD' })` from the `Game` component.

Then, encapsulate all your synchronous logic within your reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
  board: [],
  boardSize: {
    rows: 25,
    columns: 40
  }
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INITIALIZE_BOARD': {
      const { rows, columns } = state.boardSize
      const board = [];

      for (let row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
        for (let column = 1; column <= columns; column++) {
          board.push({
            id: `#cell-${row}-${column}`,
            row,
            column,
            hasFood: false,
            hasSnake: false
          });
        }
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        board
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```